# Python Error: Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def process_cars(text_file):
    total_cmpg = 0
    for line in text_file:
        if((line % 2) == 0):
            city_mpg = (line[52:54])
            print(city_mpg)
            city_mpg = int(city_mpg)
            total_cmpg += city_mpg
    print ("Total miles per gallon in the city:", total_cmpg)
```

The error comes in the if((line % 2) == 0): I have searched on the other questions with the same error but none of them could solve the problem. The error is: Not all arguments converted during string formatting. I want to mod the position of the line. For example if it is the third line then, 2 % 2.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `line % 2` are you trying to mod the number from line?

Comment: I am trying to mode the position of the line. If it is the third line, then 2 % 2  @MooingRawr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def process_cars(text_file):
    total_cmpg = 0
    for file_line_number, line in enumerate(text_file):
        if((file_line_number % 2) == 0):
            city_mpg = (line[52:54])
            print(city_mpg)
            city_mpg = int(city_mpg)
            total_cmpg += city_mpg
    print ("Total miles per gallon in the city:", total_cmpg)
```

Based on your comments, you want to only do the if statement every x amount of lines. Try what we have above, since we are using `enumerate()` which keeps a count of what ever is next in the object. In our case it keeps the count of the line number while still giving us what the line is.

`file_line_number` is the file number line currently and `line` is the content of the line.